# IIS Hosted WCF accessing file

Tags: wcf, file, iis

In development environment

```
string AppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                string path = AppPath + "\\options.xml";
```

Works.

When Hosted by production IIS7 server I put Options.xml in the bin environment but the path produced by the above code is a asp.net temp directory.
So what is the correct technique to access the file in both development and production environment?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this information you are using to support your service?
If so, is there any reason you couldn't just make a custom config class and read it as a section from your web.config?

Comment: Sounds like an elegant solution. My use of Web.config is rudimentary at best. I'll do some digging. As a matter of interest solved immediate problem with string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\options.xml";

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```